Is the Chanukat Habayit meal a Seudat Mitzvah
According to Halacha, is the meal served at a Chanukat Habayit when you affix a mezuzah to your new home a Seudat Mitzvah? Or no, even though it is a traditional minhag is it not the status of a Seudat mitzvah?

Those who hold its seudat mitzvah:
Shu"t HaRabaz 1:43,
Shu"t Avnei Nezer Yoreah Siman 384,
Shu"t Titz Eliezer 10:32,
Ben Ish Chai Shu"t Torah Lishma Siman 484,
ארץ צבי על מסכת  שבת עמוד קע"ז (לרא"צ פרומר הי"ד)
Those who give contingencies for it to become a seudat mitzvah:

Chavot Ya’ir 70/Yam Shel Shlomo Bava Kama 7:37/Magen Avraham Orach Chaim Siman 568 Seif Katan 5- there needs to be words of Torah shared.

Shu"t Be'er Sheva Siman 70/Rambam Hilchot Melachim 7:14/בשו"ת בית ישראל לר"י הורביץ סימן נ"ח- only a seudat mitzvah if done in Israel.


Those who say its just a minhag: Radak Sefer Hashorashim ערך חנך Siman ב
These are the sources I used:
https://orot.ac.il/%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A1%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%93%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94,
Yalkut Yosef Sovea Semachot first volume
